# How dowload file by Rest API in spring boot?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I have spring boot (back) and angular7(front) app. I need to upload and download files. This my back end code

```
@Entity
@Table
public class File extends BaseEntity {
    private String fileName;
    private String fileType;
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;
```

my file repository:

```
public interface FileRepo extends CrudRepository<File, Long> {
}
```

my file service

```
@Service
public class FileService {
    private FileRepo fileRepo;

    public FileService(FileRepo fileRepo) {
        this.fileRepo = fileRepo;
    }

    public File storeFile(MultipartFile file){
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());

        try{
            File file1 = new File(fileName, file.getContentType(),file.getBytes());
            return fileRepo.save(file1);
        } catch (IOException io){
            throw new FileStorageException("" + fileName + ". !", io);
        }
    }

}
```

and my controller,where i have only two methods upload and download by id:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3_600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/file")
public class FileController {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(FileController.class);
    private FileService fileService;
    private FileRepo fileRepo;


    @Autowired
    public FileController(FileService fileService,FileRepo fileRepo){
        this.fileRepo = fileRepo;
        this.fileService = fileService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
//            fileService.storeFile(file);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(fileService.storeFile(file));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new FileStorageException("", e);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> get(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        try {
            File file = fileRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException(String.format("", id)));
//            return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(file.getFileType())).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFileName() + "\"")
//                    .body(new ByteArrayResource(file.getData()));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(file);
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

How to send right form to angular in download.
Upload works i think XD

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using FileUtils of apache commons. Construct your desired url and execute following code:

```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; //import

    URL url = getClass().getResource(filePath);
    File file = new File(url.getPath()); 
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(downloadLink), file, 10000, 10000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Dependecy:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can change the above code according to your needs. In my case I downloaded a csv file from web url.